# MapMessage not recognized as such

Tags: log4j2

I am using a software framework which on its part uses log4j-2.7 (I can't update the jars of the framework).
I have written a third party library which provides a RewritePolicy to re-format the log messages. The library uses log4j-2.7 as well.
Within the framework I do some loggings with MapMessage. However, the rewrite policy receives them as SimpleMessage or some other types of Message, but not as MapMessage.

Here is code examples from framwork:

```
var mapMessage = new MapMessage()
mapMessage.put("first", "first")
mapMessage.put("second", "second")

logger.info(mapMessage)
```

And here the rewrite method of the RewritePolicy:

```
@Override
public LogEvent rewrite(LogEvent source) {
    final Message modifiedMessage;
    Message origMessage = source.getMessage();
    if (origMessage instanceof MapMessage) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(((MapMessage) origMessage).getData());
        modifiedMessage = new SimpleMessage(createStringMessage((HashMap<String, Object>) map));
    } else {
        modifiedMessage = origMessage;
    }

    LogEvent modifiedLogEvent = new Log4jLogEvent.Builder(source).setMessage(modifiedMessage).build();

    return modifiedLogEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to the fact that the sofware platform mentioned in my post did migrate from log4j 1 to 2, and as explained here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html, I had to change the package from org.apache.log4j to org.apache.logging.log4j.